# VS 2017 does not allow scrolling of the Error List

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio 2017 seems to have a new "Feature" where you can not use the scroll bars to scroll through errors, warnings and/or messages, unless you click on one and use the the keyboard up/down arrow. The scroll bar will scroll, but wait a second or two and it will immediately scroll back to an error list line that is currently highlighted.

Does anyone know how to disable this "Feature"?

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here; I suppose this is a bug, not a feature. I reported the problem to the Visual Studio dev team:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/38280/vs-2017-does-not-allow-scrolling-of-the-error-list.html

**Update (2017-04-06):** According to the above link, the bug is fixed in an upcoming release.

**Update (2017-11-10):** For the record, the bug is fixed in the VS 2017.3 release.

Comment: Same here as well. Really annoying!